# Trouble deploying my webapp to Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

When I deploy a web app to Tomcat 9.0,I get this error. I change the extention of faph. war to faph.zip, it can ben decompressed. This file was packaged by Eclipse. Building informations show as below.

[image]
[image]

```
28-Oct-2016 11:36:55.567 信息 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/faph]
28-Oct-2016 11:37:45.704 信息 [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\faph.war
28-Oct-2016 11:37:46.013 严重 [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error while attempting to validate required application extensions
 java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4988)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

28-Oct-2016 11:37:46.014 严重 [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more components marked the context as not correctly configured
28-Oct-2016 11:37:46.014 严重 [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/faph] startup failed due to previous errors
28-Oct-2016 11:37:46.016 信息 [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\faph.war has finished in 312 ms
```

Comment: Looks like a bad MANIFEST.MF file. Did you look at it?

Comment: The content of MANIFEST.MF is Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: admin
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_111

Comment: What is the problem is this file?@Andreas

Comment: Couldn't say, since I can't read that. Edit the question to show file. Also note that your problem might be with manifest files in .jar files in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.